# AWS Cannot Create Fargate Profile

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-fargate, amazon-eks

When using the following command I get this error:
Command:
    `eksctl create fargateprofile --cluster <clusternameredacted> --namespace <namespaceredacted>`

```
Error: failed to create Fargate profile "fp-d1a04caf" on EKS cluster <clusternameredacted>: failed to create Fargate profile "fp-d1a04caf": AccessDeniedException: Account <accountnumberredacted> is not authorized to use this service
status code: 403, request id: <requestguidredacted>
```

How do i update my account to get permission to do this?

Comment: It looks like a permission error due some misconfiguration or lack of configuration. If you don't provide more context it's impossible to directly help, all I can tell you is to have a look at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/security_iam_service-with-iam.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Failed to create fargate profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59673755/failed-to-create-fargate-profile)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [most recent docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/fargate.html), AWS Fargate with Amazon EKS is currently only available in the following Regions: **us-east-2, us-east-1, ap-northeast-1, and eu-west-1**.

If you are not configured to use one of these regions you will not be authorized to use this service, sadly.

Answer (score 0):

The error message returned during this process is horrible. This could be a capacity issue, a region that is not supported, or an actual permissions configuration error.

To see which add `--verbose 5` to the eksctl command and/or go to the cloudformation console and look at the the most recent events for the cluster. If it failed and is being rolled back, it should show you some error details.

If it is a permissions error, make sure you have at least the following policy attached to the AWS user profile that is running the eksctl command:

```
# Cloud Formation
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "eksCtlCloudFormation",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "cloudformation:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}


# EKS
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "eks:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}

#Autoscaling
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "autoscaling:CreateLaunchConfiguration",
                "autoscaling:DeleteLaunchConfiguration"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:autoscaling:*:*:launchConfiguration:*:launchConfigurationName/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "autoscaling:UpdateAutoScalingGroup",
                "autoscaling:DeleteAutoScalingGroup",
                "autoscaling:CreateAutoScalingGroup"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:autoscaling:*:*:autoScalingGroup:*:autoScalingGroupName/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor2",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "autoscaling:DescribeAutoScalingGroups",
                "autoscaling:DescribeLaunchConfigurations"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}

#IAM
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:CreateInstanceProfile",
                "iam:DeleteInstanceProfile",
                "iam:GetRole",
                "iam:GetInstanceProfile",
                "iam:RemoveRoleFromInstanceProfile",
                "iam:CreateRole",
                "iam:DeleteRole",
                "iam:AttachRolePolicy",
                "iam:PutRolePolicy",
                "iam:ListInstanceProfiles",
                "iam:AddRoleToInstanceProfile",
                "iam:ListInstanceProfilesForRole",
                "iam:PassRole",
                "iam:DetachRolePolicy",
                "iam:DeleteRolePolicy",
                "iam:GetRolePolicy"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:iam::<AWS Acct Id>:instance-profile/eksctl-*",
                "arn:aws:iam::<AWS Acct Id>:role/eksctl-*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}

#Networking
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "EksInternetGateway",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ec2:DeleteInternetGateway",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:internet-gateway/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "EksNetworking",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress",
                "ec2:DeleteSubnet",
                "ec2:DeleteTags",
                "ec2:CreateNatGateway",
                "ec2:CreateVpc",
                "ec2:AttachInternetGateway",
                "ec2:DescribeVpcAttribute",
                "ec2:DeleteRouteTable",
                "ec2:AssociateRouteTable",
                "ec2:DescribeInternetGateways",
                "ec2:CreateRoute",
                "ec2:CreateInternetGateway",
                "ec2:RevokeSecurityGroupEgress",
                "ec2:CreateSecurityGroup",
                "ec2:ModifyVpcAttribute",
                "ec2:DeleteInternetGateway",
                "ec2:DescribeRouteTables",
                "ec2:ReleaseAddress",
                "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupEgress",
                "ec2:DescribeTags",
                "ec2:CreateTags",
                "ec2:DeleteRoute",
                "ec2:CreateRouteTable",
                "ec2:DetachInternetGateway",
                "ec2:DescribeNatGateways",
                "ec2:DisassociateRouteTable",
                "ec2:AllocateAddress",
                "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups",
                "ec2:RevokeSecurityGroupIngress",
                "ec2:DeleteSecurityGroup",
                "ec2:DeleteNatGateway",
                "ec2:DeleteVpc",
                "ec2:CreateSubnet",
                "ec2:DescribeSubnets"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```